# I'd like to know if this question is valid. "collectors and providers of the data must have ownership rights."

Tags: american-english, british-english, questions, reading

I was trying to solve a problem and got a question.
Based only on the text, can you determine whether the sentence mentioned is correct or not?
I don't think it's appropriate to ask if it's true because the writer haven't decided who "should" own the data.
Of course, I know that if companies don't use the provider's data wisely, it could be a problem, but I don't know why the question's maker had to use the word "Must".

---

**Question. Select whether or not a mention matches the content of the following text.**

What are the issues that deserve careful deliberation? One of the biggest concerns is the question of whether or not past data can be used to predict future events. The results of Big Data analyses may mean that some people are denied health insurance coverage because of their family's genetic history, or that others could be put on watch lists because their past behavior indicates possible future criminal activities. History tells a story, but the future is always unknown. Another concern is whether the collector of the data or the provider of the data has ownership rights. For example, many companies sell their customers' personal information for commercial purposes. Both the buyer and the seller can make financial gains, but the customers that provide the information are left out. Like any resource, using it wisely can be beneficial, but using it carelessly can lead to unexpected outcomes.

- collectors and providers of the data must have ownership rights. [T/F]

Comment: You’re not deciding whether it’s true or not. You’re deciding whether that thought was expressed or not.

Comment: The thought was not expressed. The quoted content is not in the paragraph.